# jQuery.map() and undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

In playing with jQuery's utility method, `jQuery.map()`, I noticed that an undefined return value is omitted from the returned array. What is the reason for this?

```
var letters = ['a', undefined, 'c', undefined, 'e'];
console.log(letters); //["a", undefined, "c", undefined, "e"] 
console.log(letters.length); //5 

var lettersMapped = $.map(letters, function(item, index){
    var item = item;
    return item;
});

console.log(lettersMapped); //["a", "c", "e"]
console.log(lettersMapped.length); //3
```

Comment: Maybe the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) has an answer? *The function can return: [...] null or undefined, to remove the item*

Comment: @Jon please see my comment below regarding the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation for [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

> The function can return:
>
> - the translated value, which will be mapped to the resulting array
> - `null` or `undefined`, to remove the item
> - an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array

In other words, this is the expected behaviour of `jQuery.map`.

Comment: Thanks but I had already read the documentation. Clearly, this is intended behavior. My question is *why* is that the intended behavior, as this could yield unintended results. For instance, what if I want the item to be undefined?

Comment: @maxhallinan: Although that part's consequences are not as immediately clear, you can also return *an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array*. So: `return item === undefined ? [undefined] : item`. Same for `null`. In any case, your original question was perfectly answered by "read the docs". And *why* this is the chosen behavior can only be definitively answered by a couple of people on the planet -- the ones who designed it.

Comment: @Jon Fair enough. I meant why as in "is there an obvious good reason for this that I'm missing." Very much like your workaround. Please post this comment as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @maxhallinan: I don't think copy/pasting the above into another answer would offer anything. Feel free to accept this one instead.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the tip -- you can always return `[null]` or `[undefined]`. @maxhallian It's an easy way to remove elements from the array. Say, for instance, I have an array of numbers and I want to filter only the positive ones: `var numbers = $.map([-3, 5, -2, 6, 8], function (n) { return n > 0 ? n : undefined; });`. That's a little more concise (IMHO) than `var numbers = []; $.each([-3, 5, -2, 6, 8], function (i, n) { if (n > 0) { numbers.push(n); } });`